# Why is the combiner never called in spark aggregateByKey?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to understand how `aggregateByKey` work in spark

The example below converts

```
("David", 6), ("Abby", 4), ("David", 5), ("Abby", 5))
```

to

```
(Abby,Set(5, 4))
(David,Set(5, 6))
```

With the code below

```
    val babyNamesCSV = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("David", 6), ("Abby", 4), ("David", 5), ("Abby", 5)))

    babyNamesCSV.aggregateByKey(new HashSet[Int])(
        (k,v) => {
            println("start")
            println(k)
            println(v)
            println("end")
            k += v
        }, 
        (v,k) => {
            println("start2")
            println(k)
            println(v)
            println("end2")
            v ++ k
        }).map(line => {
            println(line)
            line
        }).take(100)
```

I observed that the combiner `println` never showed on `sbt` terminal even though the `seqOp` did, is there a reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you work in `local` mode (not cluster/yarn etc), the only thing I can imagine is that `babyNamesCSV` has only 1 partition, this can happen if you have only 1 core or you set `spark.master=local[1]`. In this case the combiner is never called because no partitions must be merged...

Try to set the number of partitions explicitly:

```
val babyNamesCSV = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("David", 6), ("Abby", 4), ("David", 5), ("Abby", 5)), numSlices = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding a third element in the input with one of the keys in your data. Then, lookout for printlns from both functions.

The reason may be, the workers/executors that are not on the same machine/jvm as the driver cannot show their stdout to your driver program. Hope this helps.